# XML validation gives validation error, but I can't find the cause

Tags: xml, xsd

I've tried to design an XML schema, but I keep getting stuck. My XML file won't validate against my schema. I suspect that I'm making some beginner's mistake. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? The error message doesn't make sense to me.

Here's my xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/teststuff/XMLnamespace" >
    <xs:element name="dataCollecFile">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="fileHeader" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="data" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="fileFooter">
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here's the content of the XML file that won't validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<dataCollecFile xmlns="http://www.test.com/teststuff/XMLnamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/teststuff/XMLnamespace test.xsd">
   <fileHeader>heady head header</fileHeader>
   <data>data data</data>
   <fileFooter>foot feet feeter</fileFooter>
</dataCollecFile>
```

Finally, here's the error message that I get from Java's javax.xml.validation.Validator class:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'fileHeader'. One of '{fileHeader, data, fileFooter}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to your <schema> element.

UPDATE

When elementFormDefault is unqualified, global elements will hav the target name space, but local elements will hav no namespace. So, if you had the unqualified version of the schema, your XML would have to look something like this:

```
<ns:dataCollecFile xmlns:ns="http://www.test.com/teststuff/XMLnamespace" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/teststuff/XMLnamespace test.xsd">
    <fileHeader>heady head header</fileHeader>
    <data>data data</data>
    <fileFooter>foot feet feeter</fileFooter>
</ns:dataCollecFile>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works!
Now my file validates OK.
I found an explanation of what that means at:
http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t292290-xsd-what-is-elementformdefault-qualified-for.html
But I still don't quite understand why the error was occuring for me when I didn't have that attribute set. What should my XML file look like if I wanted it to work when `elementFormDefault="unqualified"`?